# Swift - WKWebview takes a lot of time to load url

Tags: swift, performance, load, wkwebview

My mobile app uses Swift 3/ Xcode 8.3.2 and iOS 10. I have used webview/WKWebView to render website in mobile app. Because Xcode doesn't provide functionality to insert wkwebview, I have associated webview using Xcode but then programatically assigning WKWebview to it and rendering site in it. The web page loads very fast when I use WIFI (1 second) but takes approximately 10 seconds when using internet (mobile network). Any clue?

class WebSiteViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate{

```
var webURL: String? = nil
var alertRequestURL: String? = nil
var alertHeader: String? = nil
var websiteView: WKWebView!
var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false    
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""
    //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
    //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton

    if let url = URL(string: webURL!) {
      let request = URLRequest(url:url)
      websiteView.load(request)
    }

    self.spinner  = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    self.spinner.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
    self.spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
    self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.view.addSubview(spinner)
    self.spinner.startAnimating()
}

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    self.websiteView = WKWebView(frame: self.webView.frame)
    self.websiteView.uiDelegate = self
    self.websiteView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.view = self.websiteView
}
```